# jquery - hide all div except one class

Tags: jquery

Here is my code :

```
  <div id="principal" class="classxx">
    <div class="class001 cat2 blabla">
      <div class="class002">
        <div class="class003"></div>
        <div class="class004"></div>
        <div class="class005"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="class001 cat3 blabla">
      <div class="class002">
        <div class="class003"></div>
        <div class="class004"></div>
        <div class="class005"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="class001 cat1 blabla">
      <div class="class002">
        <div class="class003"></div>
        <div class="class004"></div>
        <div class="class005"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I need a function like :

```
function showOnlyCat(className){}
```

If I call `showOnlyCat('cat3')` I want to see only all the DIVs that have the 'cat3' class (each DIV has multiple classes) and its children of course

And I also need a `showAllCat()` that shows all the cat1, cat2, cat3... DIVs

Thank you VERY MUCH for your help

Comment: Wow, that's a lot of DIVs. Any chance any of them could be replaced by ULs or OLs to make the code more semantic?

Answer (score 8):

try this :

```
function showOnlyCat(cat) {
    $('div').not('.'+cat).hide();
}
function showAllCat() {
    $('div').show();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```html
$('div.cat').siblings().show();
```

And all siblings with the above will be shown.

Answer (score 1):

```
function showOnlyCat(cat){

 $('.class001').hide();
 $('.'+ cat).show();
}

function showAllCat(){
  $('.class001').show();
}
```

That's it when class001 is right.

Answer (score 0):

```
function showOnlyCat(className) {
  $('div').not('.' + className).hide();
}

function showAllCat() {
  for (i=1;i<=NUM_CAT;i++) {
    $('.cat' + i).show();
  }
}
```

Comment: I can't make it work : [http://jsfiddle.net/4DHHY/](http://jsfiddle.net/4DHHY/) I think it needs something to say that the script only affect direct children of DVI#principal

Answer (score 0):

Can be achieved with one function really

```
function toggleVisibility(className){
     if(typeof(className)!='undefined' && className != null){
        $("div").hide();         
        $("div."+className).show();
     }
   else
        $("div").show();
}
```

//to only show class001
toggleVisibilty('class001');
//to show all
toggleVisibility();

Comment: the code will be embedded in a much more complicated page, can I "limit" your script to the first children DIV of DIV#principal?

Comment: @jrm: I am not very sure what you meant. If you mean restricting the  $("div."+className).show(); to the very first div that matches the className criterion then all you have to do is  $("div."+className).eq(0).show();

Comment: Hi, not sure if my code helped or not but if it did, can you please check the checbox to indicated you accepted my answer? Thanks!