# jQuery - show/hide DIVs is they have a certain class

Tags: jquery

Here is my code :

```
  <div id="principal" class="classxx">
    <div class="class001 cat2 blabla">
      <div class="class002">
        <div class="class003"></div>
        <div class="class004"></div>
        <div class="class005"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="class001 cat3 blabla">
      <div class="class002">
        <div class="class003"></div>
        <div class="class004"></div>
        <div class="class005"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="class001 cat1 blabla">
      <div class="class002">
        <div class="class003"></div>
        <div class="class004"></div>
        <div class="class005"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I need a function like :

```
function showOnlyCat(className){}
```

If I call `showOnlyCat('cat3')` I want to see only all the DIVs that have the 'cat3' class (each DIV having multiple classes) and its children of course
The function has to target only first children of DIV#principal

And I also need a `showAllCat()` that shows all the children DIVs of DIV#principal

Thank you VERY MUCH for your help

Comment: You've already asked this question and got 4 answers to it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076461/jquery-hide-all-div-except-one-class)

Comment: @Gareth, agreed. Voting to close as an exact duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function showOnlyCat(className){
 $("#principal").children().hide().filter("."+className).show();
}

function showAllCat(){
 $("#principal").children().show();
}
```

Edit: Fixed the bugs. Tested. It works.

Edit2: Following good suggestion from @gnarf

Comment: You could chain `.filter('.'+className).show()` to the end of the `.hide()` to be more accurate...

Comment: seems correct but I can't make it work, look : [http://jsfiddle.net/wKPxz/](http://jsfiddle.net/wKPxz/)

Comment: @gnarf, can you explain a bit more?

Comment: @jrm, sorry that was the old version! New one is much better.

Answer (score 0):

hello with jQuery you can do that:

```
function showAllCat() {
    $('#principal div').each(function() {
        $(this).css('display', 'block');
    })
}

function showOnlyCat(className) {
    $('#principal div:not(.' + className + ')').each(function() {
        $(this).css('display', 'none');
    })

    $('#principal div.' + className).each(function() {
        $(this).css('display', 'block');
    })
}

//other way:
function showOnlyCat1(className) {
    //hide all
    $('#principal div').each(function() {
        $(this).css('display', 'none');
    })
    //showing only class parameter
    $('#principal div.' + className).each(function() {
        $(this).css('display', 'block');
    })
}
```